# Prove the following integrals' equality

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$ \int_a^b \frac{x^2 - 2ax + a^2}{2x^2 - 2(a + b)x + a^2 + b^2} dx = \int_a^b \frac{x^2 - 2bx + b^2}{2x^2 - 2(a + b)x + a^2 + b^2} dx $$

I tried to solve this by Partial Fractions, and did $$ 2x^2 - 2(a+b)x + a^2+b^2 = 2x(x-(a+b)) + (a^2+b^2) $$ but I can't see something else to do with this. Could you give me any hint? I'm stuck.

Comment: Add up the integrals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint as requested: note that the left hand side integral is
$$L=\int_a^b \frac{(x-a)^2}{(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2}\,dx$$
and then substitute $x=a+b-y$.

Comment: I get $\int_a^b \frac{(y - b)^2}{(y-b)^2 + (y-a)^2}$, but my question is, can I make x = y? From $x = a + b - y$, $dx = -dy$, but if dy = dx, there is a contradiction. Or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: See my answer to your comment below.

Comment: The name of the variable in a definite integral is irrelevant; for this reason it is sometimes called a "dummy variable".  If you are not comfortable with this, calculate$$\int_2^3x^2\,dx\quad\hbox{and}\quad \int_2^3t^2\,dt\quad\hbox{and}\quad \int_2^3y^2\,dy\ .$$You will see that they all give the same answer, and not only that, but they give the same answer *for the same reasons*.

Answer (score 2):

We make the substitution $u = a+b-x$. Then we have \begin{align*}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^2-2ax+a^2}{2x^2-2(a+b)x+a^2+b^2} \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x &= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{(x-a)^2}{(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \int_{b}^{a}\frac{(b-u)^2}{(b-u)^2+(a-u)^2}\left(-\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u\right) \\ &= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{(u-b)^2}{(u-a)^2+(u-b)^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u \\ &= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{(x-b)^2}{(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x \\ &= \int_{a}^{b}\frac{x^2-2bx+b^2}{2x^2-2(a+b)x+a^2+b^2}\end{align*} as required.

Comment: In the second to the fourth line, how did you past, first, from b to a to a to b, and then, how did you past from $u - b$ to $x - b$?

Comment: Switching the limits negates the integral (this is a well-known result). Therefore, we can use the negative sign from $\left(-\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u\right)$ to switch the limits. After that, $u$ or $x$ is just a dummy variable, e.g. if you work out $\int_{1}^{2}x^2 \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x$, you will do exactly the same calculations as if you work out $\int_{1}^{2}k^2 \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}k$ or $\int_{1}^{2}\gamma^2 \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\gamma$. Therefore, we can simply switch all the $u$s to $x$s.